# liquid-vapor interface goldstone modes

Tags: phase-transition, goldstone-mode

The free energy of a liquid-vapor interface (far from critical point) can be approximates as
$$
\mathcal{F}=γ A+\frac{γ}{2}\int dxdy|\nabla h(x,y)|^2
$$
where $h(x,y)$ is the height of the interface at a given point (x, y), $\gamma$ is the surface tension, and A is the area of a completely flat interface. What are the goldstone modes appearing in the system, and which symmetry breaking is responsible for them?

I imagine the way to solve such a question would be to decompose h into its fourier components, but I am not sure how to word the symmetry broken here.

Answer (score 0):

No symmetries are broken at the liquid-gas phase transition. Therefore no Goldstone modes are expected either.

Comment: Is this due to the Mermin Wagner Theorem (no continuous symmetries broken in d<=2?)

Comment: No, this is due the formulation of the Goldstone theorem.